# left and center aligning in same line using XSL FO

Tags: xsl-fo

I saw this in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391759/xsl-fo-inline-alignment),

```
<fo:block text-align-last="justify"> 
   LEFT TEXT
<fo:leader leader-pattern="space" />
   RIGHT TEXT
</fo:block>
```

But i want the RIGHT TEXT to be aligned to center of the same line. I am using Apache FOP to generate PDF from xml. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a one row, three column table with column widths like 30-40-30 or whatever you need to accommodate the text widths. Put the content in the first two cells only and set the alignment on them to left and center respectively.