# XSL FO inline alignment for the VF pages

Tags: pdf, apex, xsl-fo, visualforce, quote

I need to get text aligned centre and right on the same line. This should be possible, but I can't seem to find a way. I'm using these tags in VF page for the quote document.

Can someone help me to get this right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand 'VF page', but this should work for you:

```
<fo:block>a<fo:leader leader-length.optimum="100%" />b</fo:block>
```

Comment: Hello Tony, could we align the first text at the centre and another text at the right side on the same line?

Comment: You could use a table, as in @KevinBrown's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23961277/4092205

Comment: Is there any solution using <fo:leader> and <fo:block>. Instead of creating table inside a table for allignment.