# XSLFO Transferring the word to the right border of the document

Tags: xsl-fo

There is a line:
"Table Name \ City."
Is there a way to transfer the word city to the right border of the document in the block?

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/590335/407651.

Comment: @mzjn Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSL FO inline alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391759/xsl-fo-inline-alignment)